# Angular 2 bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript

Trabajo con Angular 2 cuando uso el import para bootstrap no lo reconoce este es un archivo `.ts` estoy usando Typescript. No puedo importar `bootstrap`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
    selector: 'hola-angular',
    template: '<h1> {{saludo}} </h1>'
})
class HolaAngularComponent{
    saludo: string;
    constructor(){
        this.saludo = '!Hola Angular 2¡';
    }
}
bootstrap(HolaAngularComponent);
```

Me da el siguiente error

```
l módulo '"./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"' no tiene ningún miembro 'bootstrap' exportado.
```

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Qué es lo que intentas hacer con ese `bootstrap`?

Comment: Importalo poner el namespace, estoy siguiendo un curso video tutorial

Comment: Agrega más contexto porque no se me hace familiar eso de importar el `bootstrap`. Lo más cercano que encuentro es la función `angular.bootstrap()` pero es de AngularJS.

Comment: @Lobos Estoy trabajando con angular 2

Answer (score 1):

Logré solucionarlo.

El error yacía en `import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform...`, se debe importar `platformBrowserDynamic` en lugar de  `bootstrap`.

El `platformBrowserDynamic` es quien contiene el `Bootstrapping` para la aplicación.

Código completo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
    selector: 'hola-angular',
    template: '<h1> {{saludo}} </h1>'
})
class HolaAngularComponent{
    saludo: string;
    constructor(){
        this.saludo = '!Hola Angular 2¡';
    }
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(HolaAngularComponent)
```